# Error in web scraping response a page title

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to be a code for analysing a bet graphics. What the error has ocurred in the log ?
I took the test with other famous sites and I couldn't get a response either.

```
scrapy runspider av/av/spiders/av.py                               

2022-03-05 14:46:38 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.6.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
2022-03-05 14:46:38 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.8.0.0, libxml2 2.9.12, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 22.2.0, Python 3.10.2 (tags/v3.10.2:a58ebcc, Jan 17 2022, 14:12:15) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 22.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021), cryptography 36.0.1, Platform Windows-10-10.0.22000-SP0
2022-03-05 14:46:38 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'SPIDER_LOADER_WARN_ONLY': True}
2022-03-05 14:46:38 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2022-03-05 14:46:38 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: a318c628cfaf76a9
2022-03-05 14:46:38 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2022-03-05 14:46:38 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2022-03-05 14:46:38 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2022-03-05 14:46:38 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2022-03-05 14:46:38 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2022-03-05 14:46:38 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-05 14:46:38 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2022-03-05 14:46:39 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://aviator-next.spribegaming.com/?user=896541&token=2c5aa7d41630609ddf82e58655f7299e3106a6377b678d50740ab7aa5925afdf&lang=pt&currency=BRL&return_url=&operator=demo&jurisdiction=CW> (referer: None)
2022-03-05 14:46:39 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://aviator-next.spribegaming.com/?user=896541&token=2c5aa7d41630609ddf82e58655f7299e3106a6377b678d50740ab7aa5925afdf&lang=pt&currency=BRL&return_url=&operator=demo&jurisdiction=CW> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Antônio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 857, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(  # type: ignore[misc]
  File "C:\Users\Antônio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 67, in _parse
    return self.parse(response, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Antônio\Desktop\av\av\av\spiders\av.py", line 9, in parse
    title = response.css('title::text').extract.first()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'first'
2022-03-05 14:46:39 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2022-03-05 14:46:39 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 375,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 7445,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 1.152582,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 5, 17, 46, 39, 869740),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 9849,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'spider_exceptions/AttributeError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 5, 17, 46, 38, 717158)}
2022-03-05 14:46:39 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Above is the error log, below is my code, a very simple code just to try to receive the test information from the page

```
import scrapy

class AvSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'av'
    allowed_domains = ['aviator-next.spribegaming.com']
    start_urls = ['https://aviator-next.spribegaming.com/?user=896541&token=2c5aa7d41630609ddf82e58655f7299e3106a6377b678d50740ab7aa5925afdf&lang=pt&currency=BRL&return_url=&operator=demo&jurisdiction=CW']

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.css('title::text').extract.first()
        print(title)
        pass
```

I want to receive a simple title, if it works i want to be start my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extract the first thing that matches, use the method `extract_first()`

```
import scrapy

class AvSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'av'
    allowed_domains = ['aviator-next.spribegaming.com']
    start_urls = ['https://aviator-next.spribegaming.com/?user=896541&token=2c5aa7d41630609ddf82e58655f7299e3106a6377b678d50740ab7aa5925afdf&lang=pt&currency=BRL&return_url=&operator=demo&jurisdiction=CW']

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.css('title::text').extract_first()
        print(title)
        pass
```

This is currently working here for me and printing 'Aviator' as the title.